# WPF Image Source is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to overlay an image on my `BoardSquares` but when trying to specify a `Source` on my `Image` it says `The member "Source" is not recognized or is not accessible`. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? P.S I omitted the DataTemplate Triggers but they're there.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BoardGUI.BoardSquares}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="10" Columns="10"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="Square"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.BoardGUI.SquareClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Source}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Button class doesn't have Source property, `{TemplateBinding Source}` won't work. What is that `Source`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

{TemplateBinding Source} tries to bind to a Source property of the templated parent which is the Button in this case and a Button has no Source property.

If the type of objects in the BoardSquares source collection has a Source property you should use the **{Binding}** markup extension to bind to this:

```
<Button.Template>
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
     <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Image Source="{Binding Source}"/>
     </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Button.Template>
```

If you simply want to set the Source property of the Image to a non-dynamic image source, you could just specify a Uri to this image:

```
<Image Source="Images/pic.png"/>
```

Comment: I much prefer answers that Explain the problem as well as provide the answer +1